# RChannel Sensitivity in DICOM waveforms

Tags: dicom, waveform

I am trying to make an ECG viewer reading DICOM files.

I get all data (like Channel Definition Seqeunce), also got the waveform samples to each channel. My problem is that there is a Tag (Channel Sensitivity), and I can't figure out it's meaning.

What purpose does it have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you have the raw value for a sample you have to apply some transformations defined by several tags.

**Channel Sensitivity** is a mandatory field when samples represent defined units and it must be used in conjunction with **Channel Sensitivity Correction Factor**, **Channel Baseline** and **Channel Sensitivity Units**. It represents numeric value of unit quantity of sample.

What does it means? Suppose you did read the sample, you added the bias of Channel Baseline and applied the correction factor of Channel Sensitivity Correction Factor.

Now that value matches Channel Sensitivity with the unit of Channel Sensitivity Units. For example suppose you acquired a constant 5 mV signal, you may set Sensitivity to 5 mV, write to disk the value 1 for each sample and use a Channel Sensitivity Correction Factor of 5. After decoding you'll have back 5 mV. You do not need to consider this (but you have to consider its unit) if you'll display the signal with the same sensitivity.

For your reference: http://dicomlookup.com/html/03_03PU.html#LinkTarget_229394

Comment: So if I undestand correctly, the Channel Sensitivity is a reference value.
In my example, raw sample values ranging from ~ -70 to 150, BaseLine is 0, Ch. Sensitivity is 2.5, Ch.Sens.Correction Factor 1,
Code meaning is microvolt.
So I get a sample ( value 12 + BaseLine 0 ) * Correction Factor 1 and my final value is 12?

Comment: Yes, now to get the FINAL value multiply 12 and 2.5 and you'll get 30 uV. Imagine to set the sample to "1", do all math then what you'll get is the value represented by the channel sensitivity. In this way you maximize the "dynamic range" of your signal keeping as much information as you did acquire (sensitivity for a device with +/- 65 mV input dynamic isn't the same of a device with +/- 1 mV device).