# Plotting the Graph against ECG Modality

Tags: dicom

ECG

I have no previous experience in plotting the Graph. I want to plot ECG Graph w.r.to their Waveform Sequence How it can be achieve and below are some points that also i need to ask....

1)I want to draw ECG from ECG Modality.

2)For this how to draw the graph and what type of co-ordinate i need to consider.

3)which dicom tags are helpful to draw graph w.r.to to point to draw

```
    (5400, 0100) Waveform Sequence 

         1) "5.6.3-9-1",        // "I"
         2) "5.6.3-9-2",        // "II",
         3) "5.6.3-9-61",       // "III",
         4) "5.6.3-9-62",       // "aVR",
         5) "5.6.3-9-63",       // "aVL",
         6) "5.6.3-9-64",       // "aVF",
         7) "5.6.3-9-3",        // "V1",
         8) "5.6.3-9-4",        // "V2",
         9) "5.6.3-9-5",        // "V3",
        10) "5.6.3-9-6",        // "V4",
        11) "5.6.3-9-7",        // "V5",
        12) "5.6.3-9-8",        // "V6"
```

4)How to plot the graph intervals along with (X,Y) axis and which values are        shown over the graph from which dicom tags are necessary to show ECG values over graph.

give me details that are necessary for ECG modality (i.e. the relationship between the ECG tags that need to follow).

Thanks for reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a too general question. You should start reading the documentation about Dicom waveforms and then ask more specific questions.

Anyway, you can find a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12855400/rchannel-sensitivity-in-dicom-waveforms) here. May be this helps as a starting point.

The answers:

1. Nice :-)
2. You will have two axis. One of them (X axis) represents time (usually ms)
   while the other (Y axis) represents signal level (usually mV)
3. A lot of. You could start having a look at a Dicom dictionary. In particular, you should pay attention to **data elements** from groups `003A` and `5400`
4. Closely related to question #3

Comment: thanks for reply
In (0040,B020)Annotation Sequence tag contains (0040,A0B0) Reference Waveform Channels tag with value 1\0 also "Temporal Range Type value POINT, Referenced Sample Positions value 256, Annotation Group Number value 2" is this tags are link up or relation with data elements from groups 003A and 5400 if yes then how?

Comment: Not sure. I think this one refers only to annotations.